# Creating an Overloaded function double.TryParse without an output parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

I have a program that needs to test to see if a string can be converted to a double but has no use for the converted double value.

I could create my own TryParse method in my own NameSpace, but shouldn't I be able to add an overloaded form of the function in the same namespace that has no output param?

```
namespace System
{
    using System;

    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: Update summary.
    /// </summary>
    public class Double
    {
        public bool TryParse(string value)
        {
            double outDouble;
            return Double.TryParse(value, out outDouble);
        }
    }

}
```

I get this error:

```
Error   1   No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 2 arguments
```

because my class is hiding the real Double class.

**Update:**

Same error with this:

```
namespace System
{   
    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: Update summary.
    /// </summary>
    public static class Double
    {
        public static bool TryParse(string value)
        {
            double outDouble;
            return global::System.Double.TryParse(value, out outDouble);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, but I don't think that is how the "real" tryParse is implemented. For example, this is not valid: double x;
x.TryParse

Comment: The real `TryParse` is a static (class) method. Extension methods always behave like instance methods.

Comment: @David: That sounds right, and, iiuc, why an extension method is not what I want

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to implement your own _Double_ class (not struct?) in _System_ namespace (or any other namespace). It's just asking for troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are *hiding* the `System.Double` type with your *own* `System.Double`. This means that when you try to call `System.Double.TryParse`, the compiler is looking at your class and that's the error being reported.

You need to either change your namespaces or class names.

Comment: You'll still need to qualify which double you're using in order to actually call this, though, right?

Comment: @Rawling - Not sure. Probably.

Comment: OK, so the answer is "you cannot overload that method", because changing the Class name or the namespace results in a separate method, not an overload.

Comment: @ChadD - What you are doing is not overloading a method. It can't be, as you can't inherit from a Value type like `Double`.

Comment: @Oded-I didn't think I was trying to inherit the Double value type, I though that I was creating a new static method in a Static class System.Double. I was hoping adding the "partial class" would word. It didn't

Comment: @ChadD - My point was that this is not overloading. You are creating a _different_ type that simply shares a _name_ with the existing type.

Comment: @Oded-Hmmm: System.Double is a struct, not a class, and I don't think the Partial keyword applies. If it were a class, I'm thinkingf that it may have worked.

Comment: @ChadD - Only if the class was not sealed, which many such constructs are in the BCL. And you would need to inherit from the type first (and still, not reuse the name).

Answer (score 2):

I would create an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx). As you can't create a static Extension method (the `TryParse` method is a static method), you'll have to put it somewhere else. As I see that your parameter is just a string, you can add an extension method to `string`, for example named `IsDouble`.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsDouble(this string value)
        {
            double outDouble;
            return Double.TryParse(value, out outDouble);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why would you name the method "IsBoolean" and test to see if its actually a double? Why not IsDouble?

Comment: @justnS : Typo, oops, fixed that ;). (My head is not too clear anymore after a long day of work.)

Comment: That works but the question was asking if it was possible to overload the existing TryParse, not to implement it a different way. :-) If I overload an existing method, I don't have 2 places to look for what is really the same function.

Comment: And I answered that also ;). "As you can't create a static Extension method (the TryParse method is a static method), you'll have to put it somewhere else."